# Export elements of a list to separate excel files in R

Tags: r, export

I've got a list of 24 dataframes and I'm wondering if there's an easy way to export each element to its own excel file from R, preferably using the name of the list element in the excel files title?

I know I can do `write.xlsx(listofdfs, "newexcelfilename.xlsx")` and it will put each element into its own worksheet within the file, but in my case I'll eventually need to email these files separately so it is best if I can get them into their own individual excel file. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use any of the apply function in base R.  For example, using  `Map` -

```
Map(openxlsx::write.xlsx, listofdfs, paste0(names(listofdfs), '.xlsx'))
```

Also with `purrr::imap` -

```
purrr::imap(listofdfs, ~openxlsx::write.xlsx(.x, paste0(.y, '.xlsx')))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Tried your first solution and it worked perfectly. Saved me a good 30 mins of copy/pasting.